# Error when adding `image_painter: ^0.4.5`

Tags: flutter, dart

Error when adding `image_painter: ^0.4.5`

I try to add this library to my new project, but i getting error like below:

```
Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on vector_math 2.1.0 and image_painter >=0.4.5 <1.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on vector_math ^2.1.1, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with image_painter >=0.4.5 <1.0.0-nullsafety.0.
So, because painter_image depends on both image_painter ^0.4.5 and flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in painter_image...                           
pub get failed (1; So, because painter_image depends on both image_painter ^0.4.5 and flutter_test
any from sdk, version solving failed.)
```

Thankyou for any helping

Comment: I suggest you to add new library using terminal, ex `flutter pub add image_painter` then `flutter pub get`.

Comment: This is work! Thank you!

Comment: This works because you add the lastest version (^0.4.5) which is the alternative to using vector_math ^2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

If you get an error that starts with `Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on...` you have conflicting package versions. This is the reason because different packages (or your project itself) might depent on different versions of the same package.

In your case your project depends on `vector_math 2.1.0` and `image_painter >=0.4.5 <1.0.0-nullsafety.0` depends on **vector_math ^2.1.1**,

Which is causing flutter_test from sdk to be incompatible with `image_painter >=0.4.5 <1.0.0-nullsafety.0.`

So, because `painter_image` **depends on both** `image_painter ^0.4.5` and `flutter_test any` from sdk, version solving failed.

**That is what this error means, so how to solve it?**

- You need to change image_painter to a range of versions: `vector_math ^2.1.1 and image_painter: ^0.4.5`

The [caret syntax](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#caret-syntax) (^) is a compact way to represent version ranges.

> ^version means the range of all versions guaranteed to be backwards
> compatible with the specified version.
>
> For example, ^1.2.3 is equivalent to '>=1.2.3 <2.0.0', and ^0.1.2 is
> equivalent to '>=0.1.2 <0.2.0'.

**Please replace**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  vector_math 2.1.0
  image_painter >=0.4.5 <1.0.0-nullsafety.0
```

with

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  vector_math ^2.1.1
  image_painter: ^0.4.5
```

Comment: I still get error with yours. But, thankyou for helping and do the long explanation, i solve it with this `flutter pub add image_painter`.

Comment: Sorry had an editing error, the point is you need to add the latest versions of both packages to be sure, that they will be supported. Since the specified range or version itself (as you did with image_painter) will not be enough.

Comment: @EkoMuhammadRiloPembudi By default, dart pub add uses the latest stable version of the package - which is the one specified by me - just make sure you understand that command :)